# UITextView maximum length

Tags: uitextview, max

I am adding a text to a `UITextView` object, but the complete text does not show.
If I do this:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [self.txtview.text length]);
self.txtview.text = lstrdetails;
NSLog(@"%d", [self.txtview.text length]);
```

I got 0 and 12162 respectively. I guess 12162 is the maximum. Does anybody know how to increment this maximum value so my complete text appears?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that length of `lstrdetails` is greater than 12162?

I tried this:

```
self.dataField.text = @"";
int i = 0;
while(i < 1000000)
{
    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@x", self.dataField.text];
    self.dataField.text = str;    
    i++;
    NSLog(@"I: %i, LENGTH: %i", i, [str length]); 
}
```

(it's very unoptimized)

`2012-03-24 09:51:35.178 test[7942:f803] I: 15454, LENGTH: 15454`, and couting !

**EDIT:**

- with increment of 200 char at a time: `I: 100000, LENGTH: 100000`, and couting !
- with 1000 by 1000 : `I: 330000, LENGTH: 330000`, and couting !

(OS X 10.7, 4 Go RAM, XCode 4.2.1, iPhone project with ARC)

Comment: It's true...12162 comes form the text length...Which means that the limit for UITextView is shorter than that, because the text is still not been completely displayed....What can I do?? How can I visualize the whole text?

Comment: May be try to change height of UITextView and use a scroll view?